Trouble when dealing with HttpOnly Cookie between an ASP.NET Core Web API and ReactJS
To give you some context I am currently working on improving my ASP.NET Core Web API skills by trying to implement a Refresh/Access based authorization between an ASP.NET Core Web API and a ReactJS application.
I have done some testing and when I use tools such as ThunderAPI and Insomnia. It does work as expected. But when I try to try them out with the React app itself it does work.. Just not as expected.
I have the login endpoints like so:
Frontend:
export const signIn = async (data: LoginFormData):Promise<LoginResponseData> => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/auth/login`,{
        method: "POST",
        headers:{
            "Content-type":"application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong...");
    }
    const returnJson = await response.json();
    localStorage.setItem("accessToken",returnJson.accessToken);
    return returnJson;
}

Backend:
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequestDto loginModel)
{
    var user = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == loginModel.Username);

    if (user == null) 
        return BadRequest("Wrong username or password");

    var passwordMatch = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginModel.Password);

    if (!passwordMatch) 
        return BadRequest("Wrong username or password");

    var refreshToken = _tokenServices.CreateRefreshToken(user);
    Response.Cookies.Append("auth_token", refreshToken, new CookieOptions()
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = false, // For dev Purposes
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
            });

    var accessToken = _tokenServices.CreateAcessToken(user);

    return Ok(new { AccessToken = accessToken });
}

As you can see fairly straightforward and tested with Insomnia and thunderAPI in which it did worked as expected.
Now the issue: when trying it out with the React app, it does reach the endpoint. It does send back and sets the access token.
The refresh token/HttpOnly token does not get sends back to the browser. I have done some research and found some probable causes for this from the CORS configuration to the way I am handling the custom functionality of how I check my bearer cookie (access token) and my HttpOnly cookie (refresh token).
Let me show you some relevant code - this is how my CORS is configured:
public static void ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
}

Implementation:
builder.Services.ConfigureCors();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

I know it should probably not be as loose as it is but for testing purposes it worked.
This is how I configured both of them in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"]!)),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var authorizationHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
            var httpOnlyCookie = context.Request.Cookies["auth_token"] ?? "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) && authorizationHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Cookies["auth_token"]) && context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("auth_token"))
                {
                    context.Token = authorizationHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = "";
                }

            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

The idea behind it was to not only rely on the access token for authentication and authorization but to have both active in order to be able to even use the access token just for extra security and since I wanted to have the logout be a simple auth_token (refresh token) replacement for an empty string one.
I know this error is probably a lack of knowledge on my part into how HttpOnly cookies work in general as well as when working with ReactJS.
So any advice, feedback or resource is more than welcome!
Thank you for your time.

on your frontend fetch call add credentials:"include" to ensure cookies are sent with the request like this :
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: "include", // Ensure cookies are sent with the request
    }

and also Use browser DevTools to verify Set-Cookie headers.
